# Bound image does not render, despite the byte[] containing the valid image data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a byte[] in my ViewModel that is bound to the `Source` property of an `Image` control in my View. The byte[] is populated with valid image data, and I can still work with the data, the image itself is just not visible on the screen.

I have implemented cropping functionality in my application, and when the image data is not rendered, I can still select an area on the image (drawing on the canvas) and crop from it, and the cropped image is rendered on the screen in its own separate control. The image data is also of the correct, expected size as my cropping tests have provided the same results when the image is visible and invisible.

This is not a constant issue either—the image is almost always displayed, but occasionally the application gets into a state where the image is no longer rendered.

View:

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True">
   <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding ImageByteArray}" Width="600" Height="776" />
   <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" Width="600" Height="776" />
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private byte[] _imageByteArray;
    public byte[] ImageByteArray
    {
        get { return _imageByteArray; }
        set
        {
            _imageByteArray= value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ImageByteArray);
        }
    }
```

Once this starts happening, I have to shut down the application in order to get it working again. At first I thought that it might be somehow related to memory use/un-freed resources, but I have seen instances of low memory use that demonstrate the problem as well.

I am at a loss as to what to do next—debugging indicates that nothing is wrong (all values I can think to check are as expected), and the only issue is that I cannot SEE the image. Everything [else] works as desired.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
There is an out of memory exception occurring in my application, but it is not caught, and does not cause a crash. When I attempted to examine values in the debugger the values read something along the lines of "Unable to resolve due to out of memory error." I would have taken screenshots, but when I tried to step through it again the problem resolved itself. It is very difficult to reproduce when running in Visual Studio, when attached to the debugger. Outside of V.S. (running the EXE) I can reproduce it more easily, but then I have no data to inspect.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with how you create the byte array. Try to change the property type to ImageSource, and always explicitly create and return a BitmapImage from a MemoryStream over the byte array, to see if any exceptions occur.

Comment: If the byte[] is wrong, then why does it work most of the time? Also, the byte[] does contain the correct image data, because I am able to crop from the byte[].

Comment: How large, in pixels, is the resulting bitmap supposed to be?